# JSON to XML with @ character in json key

Tags: java, xml

I have the following json which I want to convert to XML.

```
{
   "@test": "value"
}
```

How do I convert this to XML hadeling the @ correctly? Is this even possible?

Comment: "Correctly" doesn't tell us what you regard as correct. What XML do you want to generate from this? In general tools that convert between XML and JSON give you fairly limited control over the output.

Answer (score -1):

It is doable as per [this](https://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2018/apr/10/json-xml-jackson/).

```
String json = "{ \"@test\":\"value\" }";

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode tree = objectMapper.readTree(json);
String jsonAsXml = xmlMapper.writer().withRootName("RootTagName").writeValueAsString(tree);
System.out.println(jsonAsXml);
```

Pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Output:

```
<RootTagName><@test>value</@test></RootTagName>
```

The `@` is being preserved in the xml tag name.

Comment: The OP said they wanted XML output, but you are offering something whose output is not well-formed XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Can you please tell me what is missing from the below to be a "well-formed XML" ?
`<RootTagName><@test>value</@test></RootTagName>`

Comment: XML names cannot contain an "@" character.